# Топ людей по рейтингу

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Игровой бот vk_api
Есть текстовик с id людьми и их рейтингом.
Все люди разделены построчно.
Как грамотно сделать так, чтобы код определял, у кого больше рейтинг и присваивал id этого человека в переменную 1, у кого чуть меньше, в переменную 2 и т.д.
Пример текстовика:

`{"id" : 123457890, "reiting" : 228} {"id" : 743451890, "reiting" : 202}`

Comment: Грамотно - не раскладывать по отдельным переменным, а просто отсортировать список по ключу.

Answer (score 2):

Сортировкой по ключу можно попробовать с реверсом:

```
users = [{"id" : 123457890, "reiting" : 228}, {"id" : 743451875, "reiting" : 1}, {"id" : 743451890, "reiting" : 202}]
rated = sorted(users, key=lambda k: k['reiting'], reverse=True)
print(*rated, sep='\n')
```

На выходе будет отсортированный список.

Вывод:

```
{'id': 123457890, 'reiting': 228}
{'id': 743451890, 'reiting': 202}
{'id': 743451875, 'reiting': 1}
```

Comment: Благодарю!ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ